# Java / Kotlin getting value in for loop for step + one and also a step before if condition in for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, kotlin

I am currently creating a program to check the order status (pending or confirmed) when a user open the app now the problem is if I need to check after order time and between I am checking time (Current Time) in this timeframe check for how many times I change price and compare if price is match or not.

So how can I check a step before i. like i is 3 and I need to also include 2 in it and compare value of i and i+1 value in every loop without getting index out of bond.

Code :

```
 for (i in 0 until arrTriple!!.size){
   if (arrTriple[i].third >= ordertime){ //arrTriple[i].third is time when when I change price
      
     //Need this value also without getting indexoutofbond  = arrTriple[i+1].third 
     //So I can use my logic here.

   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I understand what you're asking. Can you start with i = to 1 and do i-1 instead of i+1? Something like this:

```
for (i in 1 until arrTriple!!.size) {
   if (arryTriple[i-1].third >= overtime {
      arrTriple[i].third
   }
}
```

You'll have an edge case where `arrTriple.size == 1` that you'd need to handle still.

EDIT:

Otherwise, just add an if-check.

```
for (i in 0 until arrTriple!!.size){
  if (arrTriple[i].third >= ordertime && (i+1) < arrTriple.size){ 

  }
}
```

Comment: No you not understand i need to check before 1 step of i then back to normal and also in my if compare two int values in same array but 1 step after i like val a = arrT[i] == arrT[i+1].

Comment: Edited my response to just add an additional check in your if statement to make sure i+1 is inside your bounds.

Comment: After it what about last value of array

Comment: The if-statement will cause it to skip that one. Depends on your use-case for what you want to do. You can put an else statement to handle that one differently.

Comment: yes correct but i also i need where if condition start like from index 3 and i need to compare also index 2 in it.

Comment: Well, the way arrays work, if index 3 is valid, then index 2, 1, and 0 will be valid as well.

Comment: Then how can i now if my array's if condition is satisfied at index 3 and i need 1 index before that.

Comment: Okay no need to answer last question. My problem is resolved. Thanks Man.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need `until`. You would write it just like this

```
for(element in arrTriple!!){
    if(element.third >= ordertime){ 
        // Your logic here
    }
}
```

This would be my approach

Comment: Then how can i compare 1 step after value with current value and also i need feom where if condition start like from index 3 in need to compare also index 2 in it.